# how to formulate in lp_solve() for MST graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, pulp

I am an amateur to Python and PuLP.

That said I am currently stumbling over the syntax of PuLP. I tried to search in many places, I only found basic examples with variables having one index or simple sums.

The following is the basic problem I want to implement:

```
minimize :-  summation of C(i,j)*X(i,j)     where (i,j∈ E)
#constrains:
Subject To:-  summation of X(i,j) =n-1

summation of X(i,j) >= 1   where (i,j∈ E)

X(i,j) ∈ {0, 1}  where for all  (i,j∈ E)
```

Now I can't figure out how to formulate the objective function, nor the constraints with multiple indices.

Can you tell me how to formulate this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please show us your code in a *Minimal Example*, that you've come up with so far?

Comment: acctually i can't to do the code. If you are giving me some references or  tell me how to do then I will try.

Comment: Acctually I did it for a particular graph but I need it for generalize graph.

Comment: I want to do it in lp_solve(). using python.

Comment: Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: Actually , i want a mst graph (generalized) using above mathematical formula in lp_solve().